# Problem with spacy_initialize : Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Tags: r, spacy

I have installed spacyr and am trying to run `spacy_initialize()`. When I do so, I get the following error

> Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

`spacyr` uses `reticulate` to communicate with `python` and the module library `spacy`. For this to work `spacy` (the python module) needs to be installed on your machine and reachable for the python version reticulate is using.

In a most simple setup where you are not using `virtualenv`s or `conda` envs, running `spacyr::spacy_install()` should install it in your system library. After that `spacy_initilaize()` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion and am getting the following response > Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
In addition: Warning message:
Python '/opt/anaconda3/envs/spacy_condaenv/bin/python' was requested but '/Users/siobhanmccauley/.local/share/virtualenvs/siobhanmccauley-1aJAMhYc/bin/python' was loaded instead (see reticulate::py_config() for more information)

Comment: Restart your R session and after loading `spacyr` run `reticulate::use_condaenv("spacy_condaenv", required = TRUE)`. That way R should find the correct python version. After that you might have to run `spacy_install()` again. Or maybe `spacy_initialize()` might already work.

Comment: I tried reticulate::use_condaenv("spacy_condaenv", required = TRUE) and then spacy_initialize() but am facing the same error